# C# and XML - Read XML files from user-specified location

Tags: c#, xml, queue

Read sequentially through the XML files (e.g. C:\Application\XML) and get the xml for all the files.

Comment: Anywhere specifically that you need guidance as this is quite a broad question. I would definitely suggest looking at Linq to Xml for all your xml parsing needs.

Comment: thanks Andy, i actually want to do it without linq on VS 2005 - I mainly need help reading through a location of XMLs and placing them on a queue - i can work with queue but haven't done something similar previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read XML files as shown below:

```
List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\MyDir", "*.xml").ToList();    

foreach(string fileLocation in files)
{
      XmlDocument obj = new XmlDocument();
      obj.Load(filelocation);

      //Your code to place the xml in a queue.
}
```

Comment: thanks Rajesh, isnt there a way to just specify a location e.g. C:\XML\? and then it picks all the XML's as i've got almost 100 XMLs? thanks for your help

Comment: What is the application type you are using? Is it winforms or web application

Comment: I have modified the above code to read multiple xml files from a directory and then load them into an XmlDocument

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is implement a producer-consumer model. Have a look here: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx and scroll down to the "Producer/Consumer Queue" part.

For some classic C# XML API read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302158.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"))
 {
     var xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
            ...
 }
```